# Jquery post problem

Tags: jquery, post

```
//post data
function SubmitForm(method)
{
var login = document.form.login.value;
var password = document.form.password.value;
$.post("../content/backend.php", { login: login,password: password,method: method});
}
```

Im trying to post data using the above call. In firefox firebug flashes up an error but dose not give me time to evaluate the only thing I can see is an error point to jquery which relates to the following code.

```
// Send the data
    try {
        xhr.send(s.data);
    } catch(e) {
        jQuery.handleError(s, xhr, null, e);
    }
```

Any one know why this is happening? Entire page posted below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="../pics/homescreen.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667,    user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../javascript/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitForm(method)
{
var login = document.form.login.value;
var password = document.form.password.value;
$.post("../content/backend.php", { login: login,password: password,method: method});
}
</script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
<div id="leftnav">
<a href="../index.php"><img alt="home" src="../images/home.png" /></a>      </div>
</div>
<div id="title">Login</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<span class="graytitle">Login</span>
<ul class="pageitem">
<form name="form" method="post" action="#">
<li class="form"><input placeholder="Username" type="text" id="login"/></li>
<li class="form"><input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password"/></li>
<li class="form"><button onClick="SubmitForm('login')" name="button">Login</button></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your submit function should return false to stop event propagation.

```
function SubmitForm(method)
{
var login = document.form.login.value;
var password = document.form.password.value;
try {
    $.post("../content/backend.php", { login: login,password: password,method: method});
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
return false
}
```

To stop the default even handler from being called.

Also wrap the call inside a try/catch to make debugging easier. It's hard for us to debug the code since we don't have the called script.

Comment: Can you add some logging in your PHP file to see if the file is actually being reached? I like @Nadia's suggestion of using a try/catch block around your $.post, however, the form wont submit since @jason isn't using a submit button, rather a normal button with an onclick. I would also add .error and .success methods to the $.post()... eg. $.post().error(function(){alert('error here')});

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
"../content/backend.php"
```

try this

```
"/yourrootfolder/content/backend.php"
```